# Attempting to return indices of vowels in a string

Tags: python

For this code I pretty much have it so that it will return certain indices, but it counts multiple vowels in the same index. I just realized that index() only returns the first occurrence of the item, but now I've pretty much exhausted other possibilities.

```
def vowel_indices(s):
'string ==> list(int), return the list of indices of the vowels in s'
res = []
for vowel in s:
    if vowel in 'aeiouAEIOU':
        res = res + [s.index(vowel)]
return res
```

An example of this working is:

> vowel_indices('hello world')
>
> [1, 4, 7]

Instead I end up getting [1,4,4] as the return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comp with `enumerate`:

```
vowel_indices = [idx for idx, ch in enumerate(your_string) if ch.lower() in 'aeiou']
```

Comment: Alright, thank you! This works perfectly now.

Comment: You might want to apply [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/517923/674039) before checking in `'aeiou'`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `.index()` stops at the first occurrence of your vowel, so duplicate vowels that come later don't get noticed.

Instead of using `.index()`, use a counter variable (sort of like a C++ `for` loop):

```
def vowel_indices(s):
    res = []
    index = 0

    for vowel in s:
        index += 1

        if vowel.lower() in 'aeiou':
            res.append(index)

    return res
```

Or use `enumerate()`:

```
def vowel_indices(s):
    res = []

    for index, vowel in enumerate(s):
        if vowel.lower() in 'aeiou':
            res.append(index)

    return res
```